# What API Key is Required for UnstructuredLoader in LangChain's Document Loaders?

Tags: javascript, api-key, langchain

I'm currently working with the LangChain library in a Node.js project and trying to use the UnstructuredLoader from the `langchain/document_loaders/fs/unstructured` module. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import { UnstructuredLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/unstructured";

const options = {
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
};

const loader = new UnstructuredLoader(
  "src/document_loaders/example_data/notion.md",
  options
);
const docs = await loader.load();
```

I'm unsure about the `apiKey` needed in the options object for the `UnstructuredLoader`. Can someone clarify what key this should be and where I can obtain it? Is it a specific API key provided by LangChain, or does it refer to an external service API key, like AWS or another cloud provider?

Additionally, if there are any specific configuration steps or permissions needed for this key to work correctly, I would appreciate any guidance on that.

**My Error for passing the Open AI API Key:**

```
2023-12-06T11:21:21.704Z    65bd9f86-55cc-5ddf-9fb5-c26c0eac0992    ERROR   Invoke Error    {
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Failed to partition file /tmp/README.md with error 401 and message {\"detail\":\"API key is malformed, please type the API key correctly in the header.\"}",
    "stack": [
        "Error: Failed to partition file /tmp/README.md with error 401 and message {\"detail\":\"API key is malformed, please type the API key correctly in the header.\"}",
        "    at UnstructuredLoader._partition (/var/task/node_modules/langchain/dist/document_loaders/fs/unstructured.cjs:189:19)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async UnstructuredLoader.load (/var/task/node_modules/langchain/dist/document_loaders/fs/unstructured.cjs:198:26)",
        "    at async processFile (/var/task/index.js:103:21)",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/index.js:151:5)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is optional. it is used when you load document from an api. from the python source code:

```
def get_elements_from_api(
    file_path: Union[str, List[str], None] = None,
    file: Union[IO, Sequence[IO], None] = None,
    api_url: str = "https://api.unstructured.io/general/v0/general",
    api_key: str = "",
    **unstructured_kwargs: Any,
) -> List:
    """Retrieves a list of elements from the Unstructured API."""
    if isinstance(file, collections.abc.Sequence) or isinstance(file_path, list):
        from unstructured.partition.api import partition_multiple_via_api

        _doc_elements = partition_multiple_via_api(
            filenames=file_path,
            files=file,
            api_key=api_key,
            api_url=api_url,
            **unstructured_kwargs,
        )

        elements = []
        for _elements in _doc_elements:
            elements.extend(_elements)

        return elements
    else:
        from unstructured.partition.api import partition_via_api

        return partition_via_api(
            filename=file_path,
            file=file,
            api_key=api_key,
            api_url=api_url,
            **unstructured_kwargs,
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, that is the API_KEY for the Unstructured API https://unstructured-io.github.io/unstructured/

> `unstructured` is a Python package and cannot be used directly with
> TS/JS. However, Unstructured also maintains a REST API to support
> pre-processing pipelines written in other programming languages.